# Applying for Canada visitor visa while extension of stay in US pending

Tags: usa, canada, applications, visa-extensions

A traveler entered the US to visit family on a B-1/B-2 visa, and filed Form I-539 (Application to Extend Nonimmigrant Status) to extend his stay before the initial stay-until date on the admission stamp expired. Subsequent to the application, he has received Form I-797C (ASC Appointment Notice) to provide biometrics, which he has completed. The initial stay-until date on the admission stamp has since expired. Currently his case status on uscis.gov is "Case Was Updated To Show Fingerprints Were Taken".

Will the traveler currently be eligible for the Canada visitor visa, while his extension of stay in the US is pending? In his Canada visa application, should he put his home country or the US as his "country of residence" (field 7)? For the "country where applying" (field 9), should he use the date he entered the US as the "from" date and the requested end date of his US visit (on US Form I-539, pending) as the "to" date?

Are there some real examples of successfully getting the Canadian visa in this situation in the past?

Answer (score 4):

> Will the traveler currently be eligible for the Canada visitor visa

If the traveler is otherwise eligible, I don't know of any Canadian rule specifically denying eligibility in this situation.

> In his Canada visa application, should he put his home country or the US as his "country of residence" (field 7)?

Home country, he's a visitor in the US.

> For the "country where applying" (field 9), should he use the date he entered the US as the "from" date and the requested end date of his US visit (on US Form I-539, pending) as the "to" date?

Yes

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Is there some specific policy or guidelines that you could point to, in particular for the answer to the last question?